# phpMyAdmin does not well support PHP 7/8 and/or Mysql 8 (MariaDB 10)?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql-8.0

I have used the newest version Appserv 9.3.0 https://www.appserv.org/en/ and
xampp 8.1.2 https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html. Both have similar following problem.

When I tried to use WITH...AS or ROW_NUMBER(), both are introduced in MySQL 8.0, and phpMyAdmin shows some kinds of mistakes, see image has a red cross.

Does it mean phpMyAdmin not well yet support PHP or MySQL? Give me some comments.

[image]

Comment: phpMyAdmin is _written in_ PHP, it doesn't allow you to run PHP commands within it - so that bit of your statement makes no sense. But it does allow you to run SQL commands. If you've installed MySQL 8 / MariaDB 10.2 then you should be able to run such commands if they're valid. phpMyAdmin merely sends the query to the server, it does not control whether it's executable or not. It might provide hints, but have you actually tried to run the query? From your screenshot it's unclear if you've executed it or even what error you're actually getting - a red X doesn't tell us much useful info.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to copy and paste your intended query as text rather than an image? And please report also your phpMyAdmin version, which can be seen from the main page in the right hand pane. It looks to me like your query is using right single quotation marks instead of apostrophe characters, which could maybe cause some trouble there, but it could be the parser acting funny, too. Please also follow ADyson's suggestion to submit the query and see if MySQL gives any error.